# Is there Latex template for the manuscript submitted to Journal of Briefings in Bioinformatics?

Tags: bibliographies, templates, journal-publishing

I've checked the [journal website](http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/bib/for_authors/msprep_submission.html#Preparation%20of%20Manuscripts) and also searched with google. But I cannot find any template for this journal. Maybe there is truly NO such thing. But I just wish to post my question here in case of any one happened to know any useful information.

In addition, I am wondering how to format figures and references for this journal. There are guidance for formatting resolutions of figures in the website as follows, though I am just not sure how to do that.

> Figures should be supplied in an electronic format at a suitable size
>   for printing with the following resolutions: 600 dots per inch (dpi)
>   for line drawings and combinations; 300 dpi for greyscale. Please
>   ensure that the prepared electronic image files print at a legible
>   size and are of a high quality for publication.

The style of reference list looks like following.

> Style in the References section should be as follows (this is to be
>   consistent with PubMed):
>
> 1. Attwood T.K. The role of pattern databases in sequence analysis. Brief Bioinform 2000;1:45–59.
> 2. Long HC, Blatt MA, Higgins MC et al.. Medical Decision Making. Boston: Butterworth-Heinemann, 1997.
> 3. Manners T, Jones R, Riley M. Relationship of overweight to haitus hernia and reflux oesophagitis. In: Newman W (ed). The Obesity
>      Conundrum. Amsterdam: Elsevier Science, 1997,352–74.
> 4. Hou Y, Qiu Y, Vo NH et al. 23-O derivatives of OMT: highly active against H. influenzae. In: Programs and Abstracts of the Forty-third
>      Interscience Conference on Antimicrobial Agents and Chemotherapy,
>      Chicago, IL, 2003. Abstract F-1187, p.242. American Society for
>      Microbiology, Washington, DC, USA.
> 5. Public Health Laboratory Service. Antimicrobial Resistance in 2000: England and Wales.
>      http://www.hpa.org.uk./infections/topics_az/antimicrobial_resistance/amr.pdf
>      (7 January 2004, date last accessed).

What are the latex command for this format?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the easiest would be to ask someone at the journal?

Comment: For the figures: How do you prepare your figures?  If you prepare them with LaTeX in some way, the figures should be scalable, and thus the resolution should be good enough.  Otherwise, it depends on the program you use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't find an template on the website of the journal the best way is to contact the journal and ask, what they want to have to publish an article.

They know best what they need to fit their production process.  If they accept LaTeX, ask for a template and if the do not have on ask them, what they need. It could be they want documentclass article.

Because that depends on the journal I think we can't help more here.  (If you are allowed to use LaTeX we can help you if neccessary, if you know exactly what they need!).

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are looking for:
http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/bioinformatics/for_authors/submission_online.html

Just click on LaTeX template and you can [download the zip file](http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/bioinformatics/for_authors/bioinfo-template.zip) for the template.

Comment: That's template for Bioinformatics. What I needed was template for Briefings in Bioinformatics. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @AaronZeng oh I am really sorry, I rechecked my mistake. I should probably delete this.
Anyways I dropped them a mail for this query and this is what they responded.

"The journal does not use a LaTeX template. We accept paper in this format but we ask for all source files to be submitted (in an editable format), together with a pdf prepared from the se files for review purposes"

Comment: Briefings actually distributes the instructions for bioinformatics. But that does not come with the right bibliography style.

Answer (score 1):

This is the general format for Oxford University Press:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/oup-general-template/ybpypwncdxyb